# How to display a finer sphere in Graphics3D?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I'm trying to display two highly zoomed-in spheres with the following code:

```
src = {-49.276947, -7.02026463, 8334.27539};
R = 6371000;
Ha = 50000;
Graphics3D[{Point[src], Opacity[0.1], Green, Sphere[{0, 0, -R}, R], 
  Lighter@Blue, Sphere[{0, 0, -R}, R + Ha]}, 
 PlotRange -> (src + {{-R/10, R/10}, {-R/10, R/10}, {-2 Ha, 2 Ha}})]
```

[image: output]

As you can see in the output, the sphere mesh is quite coarse. How can I make it finer, so that the image I get really looked like containing spheres, not some connected triangles?

Comment: Try also ``Method -> {"SpherePoints" -> 85}``

Comment: @b3m2a1 You beat me to it. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's `Method -> {"SpherePoints" -> n}`:

```
src = {-49.276947, -7.02026463, 8334.27539};
R = 6371000;
Ha = 50000;
Graphics3D[{Point[src], Opacity[0.1], Green, Sphere[{0, 0, -R}, R], 
  Lighter@Blue, Sphere[{0, 0, -R}, R + Ha]}, 
 Method -> {"SpherePoints" -> 100}, 
 PlotRange -> (src + {{-R/10, R/10}, {-R/10, R/10}, {-2 Ha, 2 Ha}}), 
 ViewPoint -> Front]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Huh, that's neat! I've never got the idea to inspect the `Method` option of `Graphics3D`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Look around the site.  There are other ones, too (cylinder, tube, maybe more).

Answer (score 5):

You can obtain a piece of the sphere in customizable discretization with

```
DiscretizeRegion[
 RegionIntersection[
  Cuboid @@ 
   Transpose[src + {{-R/10, R/10}, {-R/10, R/10}, {-2 Ha, 2 Ha}}],
  Sphere[{0, 0, -R}, R]
  ],
 MaxCellMeasure -> {1 -> R/600}
 ]
```

You can get the underlying `GraphicsComplex` with

```
GraphicsComplex[
 MeshCoordinates[S],
 {EdgeForm[], MeshCells[S, 2, "Multicells" -> True]}
 ]
```

Comment: This seems to work, but for some reason appears to not respect the color specifications (`Green` and `Lighter@Blue` in the OP). Any remedy for this?

Comment: Yes; I added a way to get a "undecorated" `GraphicsComplex`.

Answer (score 3):

You can make a smoother sphere with NURBS.

```
ClearAll@nurbsSphere;
nurbsSphere[c : {_?NumberQ, _, _}, r_: 1] :=
 Module[{
   base = r {
       {{0,0,-1}, {0,0,-1}, {0,0,-1}, {0,0,-1}, {0,0,-1}, {0,0,-1}, {0,0,-1}},
       {{0,-1,-1}, {1,-1,-1}, {1,1,-1}, {0,1,-1}, {-1,1,-1}, {-1,-1,-1}, {0,-1,-1}},
       {{0,-1,1}, {1,-1,1}, {1,1,1}, {0,1,1}, {-1,1,1}, {-1,-1,1}, {0,-1,1}},
       {{0,0,1}, {0,0,1}, {0,0,1}, {0,0,1}, {0,0,1}, {0,0,1}, {0,0,1}}
       } /. p : {_?NumberQ, _, _} :> p + c,
   weights = {1, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 1},
   knots = {0, 0, 0, 1/4, 1/2, 1/2, 3/4, 1, 1, 1}
   },
  BSplineSurface[base, SplineDegree -> 2, 
   SplineKnots -> {Automatic, knots}, 
   SplineWeights -> {weights, 0.5 weights, 0.5 weights, weights}, 
   SplineClosed -> {False, True}]
  ]
```

Use it just like a normal Sphere:

```
Graphics3D@nurbsSphere@{0, 0, 0}
```

[image: 1]

```
Graphics3D[{Point[src], Opacity[0.1], Green, 
  nurbsSphere[{0, 0, -R}, R], Lighter@Blue, 
  nurbsSphere[{0, 0, -R}, R + Ha]}, 
 PlotRange -> (src + {{-R/10, R/10}, {-R/10, R/10}, {-2 Ha, 2 Ha}})]
```

[image: 2]

Although you end up right on the balloon knot.